# Reconnecting jdbc datasource to sybase ASE 12.5 after database restart

Tags: java, sap-ase, apache-commons-dbcp, jtds, jconnect

I have a java application that uses `jtds` driver and `commons-dbcp` as a connection pool. This  application connects to the `Sybase ASE 12.5`. From time to time `sybase` is restarted for the maintenance. After restart my application tries to reconnect to `sybase`, but it seems to fail all the time with the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Stored procedure 'dbo.pmxSystemDate' not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output). at 
    net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368) at 
    net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820) at 
    net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258) at 
    net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:632) at 
    net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:477) at 
    net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeQuery(JtdsStatement.java:1304)
```

Here is `spring` configuration of the datasource:

```
<bean id="ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sybase://dbms:6000/dbTD" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="10" />      
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="10" />
    <property name="validationQueryTimeout" value="3" />
</bean>
```

If I try to emulate the network failure by disabling and then enabling the network interface everything works as expected and my app reconnects successfully.

I have also tried `jconnect` `sybase` driver but without success.

I understand that I can workaround this issue by means of specifying fully-qualified object names, but in that case I will have a lot of editing of my sources, so I'm looking for the simpler solution.

Have anyone faced with such an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to overcome this issue I had to change validation query from

```
select 1
```

to

```
select name from dbTD..sysobjects where name='sysobjects'
```